# A construct as an independent variable?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, manova

I know that you can have a construct as a dependent variable: MANOVA or MANCOVA. Is it possible for me to have a construct as an independent variable?

I have a construct that consists of 3 variables that I want to use as my independent variable and I have one variable that I want to use as a dependent variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple regression should work, assuming all your variables are numerical. One DV and 3 IVs. So the analysis would look at how each IV is related to the DV after removing the effects of the other IV's, and also how all three combined are related to the DV.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem that might arise is that, if you include the three variables as separate variables they might be collinear.

One way to escape this is to create an actual construct variable (that is, make it a single variable). How to do this depends on the nature of the three variables, but a common method is factor analysis. A simpler method (if the variables are interval level or you are willing to pretend they are) is to simply add them up.

If you tell us what those variables are and how they are scaled, we might be able to give more advice.

Comment: I would assume those 3 variables were constructed through factor analysis in the first place. So I do not think it would be appropriate to do it again. I do agree with the collinearity